# Davinci Resolve 16: Need to restore timeline to original aspect ratio

Tags: davinci-resolve

[image: Screenshots show the problem]I'm new to DR and was trying out some different aspect ratios on one of my timelines. Somehow I messed thing up and now can't seem to get back to the original aspect ratio 1.66. attached is a screenshot of my situation. I have attempted every way of changing it back, but can't seem to make it work.  Using Mac with Catalina.

Grateful for any assistance that you are able to give me.

[![Now when I drag a clip (any clip) into the time line, it comes in like this.On their own clips are fine.
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NyQI.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NyQI.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clip you show has the **Tools** selected and **Dynamic Zoom** selected. Hence the Red and Green boxes. To return the view to normal - you can just click the Tools button (3 little lines) on the left-middle of your screenshot.

If the Aspect Ratio / Display is still wrong - you can change the custom timeline resolution in Project Settings using the Resolution button ( > < near top right) or Shift-9.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what's going on without knowing your project settings or what kind of footage you're using.  But the relevant settings are under Project Settings->Master Settings->Timeline resolution, Project settings->Master Settings->Pixel aspect ratio, and Project Settings->Image Scaling->Input Scaling->Mismatched resolution files.  Unless you're editing old DV footage or unless you used an anamorphic lens (you would know), Pixel aspect ratio should be set to Square, and Mismatched resolution files should be anything *except* "Stretch Frame to all Corners."